# How to declare common parameter

Tags: ros, parameter, rosparam, best-practices

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What is recommended ways to set common parameters in ROS?

In some of my nodes, I often want to use the same values for same purpose (e.g. subscribe/publish queue). Right now I'm setting parameters in `.launch` file. But since parameter comes with node name as prefix (e.g. /nodeNameA/paramNameB), parameters can't be generic enough (is it just because I don't know there's a way to nicely do this?).

Running a node that sets common parameters might be an option but right now I'm not planning to make such a thing, and more interested in better/ideal solutions if any. Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11914/how-to-declare-common-parameter/) by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10937 on 2011-11-11

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can easily declare parameters outside a  tag in a launch file:

```
<launch>
   <param name="common_param" value="123"/>
   <node name="node1" ... />
   <node name="node2" ... />
</launch>
```

Since these parameters are not specific to any one node, you may want to resolve them using [searchParam()](http://www.ros.org/wiki/roscpp/Overview/Parameter%20Server#Searching_for_Parameter_Keys) in your code.

---

Originally posted by [arebgun](https://answers.ros.org/users/18/arebgun/) with karma: 2121 on 2011-11-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3